# SCRIPT5007: Object expected in Internet Explorer with validation on login page

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, .net-4.5

After installing .NET 4.5 to my web server I'm getting script errors trying to access my AbleCommerce store in Internet Explorer.  I've tried setting the site to target .NET 4.0 again but it still doesn't work in IE so I'm not sure what's going on.  I'm not sure if this is a Ajax Toolkit issue or something changed after installing .NET 4.5.

I CAN login using Chrome and FireFox but accessing the login page (click My Account or Login on the top right) shows a script error if you have IE's settings to show script errors.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

> SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
>   login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fMembers%2fMyAccount.aspx, line 539 character 1
>
> document.getElementById('ctl00_wpm_Login_ctl03_LoginValidationSummary').dispose
>   = function() {
>       Array.remove(Page_ValidationSummaries, document.getElementById('ctl00_wpm_Login_ctl03_LoginValidationSummary'));
>   }
>
> (function(id) {
>       var e = document.getElementById(id);
>       if (e) {
>           e.dispose = function() {
>               Array.remove(Page_ValidationSummaries, document.getElementById(id));
>           }
>           e = null;
>       } })('ctl00_wpm_Login_ctl04_RegisterValidationSummary');

Comment: It appears to be within the asp:ValidationSummary

Comment: I had to roll back to .NET 4.0 by uninstalled 4.5 from the server (and then reinstalling 4.0) to resolve this.  Could not find a solution.

Comment: Please specify the version of IE that you're using.

Comment: The problem was experienced IE 8 thru 10. I believe it's an issue with the asp.net software I'm using and 3rd party tools they use (AJAX Toolkit is my guess) with .NET 4.5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to roll back to .NET 4.0 by uninstalling 4.5 from the server (and then reinstalling 4.0) to resolve this. Could not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Page_ValidationSummaries gets populated with ALL validation summaries, even for controls that are not rendered to the browser
Which means it ends up with nulls in it.

Or in this example here, you are trying to remove "null" from the array, which is the converse issue.